# How can i access and pass a variable value defined in return method and pass it to another component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i want to pass the variable value defined in return method and pass it to another component.

Below is the code snippet,

```
class componentname extends React.Component {
state = {
    cards: [],
};

render = () => {
    return (
        <div className="list">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>something</th>
                            <th>noname</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.shares.map((share) => {
                            const card = this.props.cards.find(card => 
                                  card.id === share.card_id);
                                  return (
                                      <tr key={share.id}>
                                      <td>{card ? card.name : share.card_id 
                                      </td>
                                      <td>{card.recipient}</td>
                        </tbody></table>
                        );}
                        {this.state.open && <another_component cardname={want to pass card.name here}/>}
```

cards and shares is an array of objects like below,
0: {name: "name", description: ""}
1: {name: "name1", description: "}

i want the card variable within map method (in 
                            {this.state.shares.map((share) => {
                                const card ) to be accessed globally such that can pass it to another_component. Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you cant do it inside `render`. You need to move it outside and do something like this :

```
componentDidMount() {
     this.state.shares.map((share) => {
         this.props.cards.find(card => 
              card.id === share.card_id);
              let returnedCard = cardVal ? card.name : share.card_id 
              this.setState({[card.id]:returnedCard})
     }
}
```

then you can access all values that has being saved from your `map` and pass it anywhere you want

Answer (score 0):

In componentDidMount you can get the cards and added to state.

```
    componentDidMount() {
    const cards = this.state.shares.map((share) => {
        return this.props.cards.find(card =>
            card.id === share.card_id);
    }
    this.setState({ cards });
}
```